# How to Freeze the column header in iReport / Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jquery, jasper-reports, ireport

I have column headings in column header band which I want to freeze and make details band (where actual data is displayed) to be scrollable.

Here is the Column Header code snippet

```
<columnHeader>
    <band height="36" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="1410" y="0" width="113" height="34" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#404040" backcolor="#BBD7EF"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Trebuchet MS" size="13" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Extra Hrs Amount]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="1616" y="0" width="90" height="34" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#404040" backcolor="#BBD7EF"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Trebuchet MS" size="13" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Parking Fees]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Opaque" x="1798" y="0" width="92" height="34" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#404040" backcolor="#BBD7EF"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Trebuchet MS" size="13" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Net Payment]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
```

Comment: can you post the code snippet and little description how you do it as it's not clear...

Comment: @Vinay Do you talk about xls document?

Comment: @Vinay Your question is unclear. Do you want to "freeze" the column header (to make it always on the top of document during scrolling)?

Comment: yes, I want to freeze the column header

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution the report x axis less than the  `<staticText>` field
 x axis ..i.e x="1410" y="0" in your code snippet. Reduce the x axis value to your requirement x="10" y ="3". The text will show in column header

Comment: How it can help to "freeze" the column header?

Comment: width and height belongs component in a band but x and y axis of text field is not belongs component but placing components in co-ordinates.Moving field in x co-ordinate will not make any exception so it will present outside band in the exact co-ordinate what we mention but can't visible in PDF so neither it will show any exception.

Comment: May the band has the width more than 1800 px... We don't know exactly